# Why single layer MLP is better than multilayer in digit classifier?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network

I am doing digit classifier with MNIST dataset using MLP Classifier. I observe very strange behaviour. Single layer classifier is better than multilayer. While increasing number of neurons in single layer seems to be increasing accuracy. Why multilayer is not better than single layer?
Here is my code:

```
param_grid={'hidden_layer_sizes':[400,300,200,100,70,50,20,10]}
grid=GridSearchCV(MLPClassifier(random_state=1),param_grid,cv=3,scoring='accuracy')
grid.fit(train_data.iloc[:,1:],train_data.iloc[:,0])
grid.grid_scores_
```

output:

```
[mean: 0.97590, std: 0.00111, params: {'hidden_layer_sizes': 400},
 mean: 0.97300, std: 0.00300, params: {'hidden_layer_sizes': 300},
 mean: 0.97271, std: 0.00065, params: {'hidden_layer_sizes': 200},
 mean: 0.97052, std: 0.00143, params: {'hidden_layer_sizes': 100},
 mean: 0.96507, std: 0.00262, params: {'hidden_layer_sizes': 70},
 mean: 0.96448, std: 0.00150, params: {'hidden_layer_sizes': 50},
 mean: 0.94531, std: 0.00378, params: {'hidden_layer_sizes': 20},
 mean: 0.92945, std: 0.00320, params: {'hidden_layer_sizes': 10}]
```

For multilayer:

```
param_grid={'hidden_layer_sizes':[[200],[200,100],[200,100,50],[200,100,50,20],[200,100,50,20,10]]}
grid=GridSearchCV(MLPClassifier(random_state=1),param_grid,cv=3,scoring='accuracy')
grid.fit(train_data.iloc[:,1:],train_data.iloc[:,0])
grid.grid_scores_
```

Output:

```
[mean: 0.97271, std: 0.00065, params: {'hidden_layer_sizes': [200]},
 mean: 0.97255, std: 0.00325, params: {'hidden_layer_sizes': [200, 100]},
 mean: 0.97043, std: 0.00199, params: {'hidden_layer_sizes': [200, 100, 50]},
 mean: 0.96755, std: 0.00173, params: {'hidden_layer_sizes': [200, 100, 50, 20]},
 mean: 0.96086, std: 0.00511, params: {'hidden_layer_sizes': [200, 100, 50, 20, 10]}]
```

About dataset: 28*28 pixel images of handwritten digits.

Comment: Did you try to tune the regularization parameter `alpha` as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that your model is overfitting. You can check that by comparing train_scores (use parameter `return_train_score=True`) with test_scores.

If it's already overfitting, then making your NN deeper or increasing units in hidden layers may make it worse. So try to get more data and/or to find a proper `alpha` (regularization parameter) to make your model perform better.

Comment: Thank you for advice. But it seems that there is no 'return_train_score' .'TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'return_train_score'.  Is there other simple way to get train scores?

Comment: @Salamat, did you pass it to `GridSearchCV()` ?

Comment: Yes.('grid=GridSearchCV(MLPClassifier(random_state=1),param_grid,cv=3,scoring='accuracy',return_train_score=True)'). I check with tab-shift there is no return_train_score parameter in my gridsearchcv.

Comment: Just checked my sklearn version it is '0.18.1'.  Probably, that is the reason.

Comment: @Salamat, i think older versions of sklearn calculate train_scores per default - check whether you see them in `grid.cv_results_.keys()`

Comment: I found problem. It was because of importing. Initially, I did :' from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV' there was no return_train_score. When I did 'from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV' it works!

Comment: Sure, I will do it as soon as I check regularisation. Still, running simulations. Thank you!

Comment: MaxU, yes it is overfitting! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I only can give a theoretical answer:

There's a theorem called ["Universal approximation theorem "](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem) which commonly says: "*Any ANN and MLP can be represented with a MLP with only 1 hidden layer.*"

So, this could be your problem. Your MLP with 1 layer has the right params for this problem, while in the other hand, you haven't find yet the right ones for the multilayer.

EDIT: More layers doesn't mean better performance. In ANN sometimes bigger it's not better. (xD)

Comment: I watch video where the did three layer NN network but in tensor flow by Martin Gorner (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u4alGiomYP4) where he used [200,100,60,30,10] hidden layer. He after some optimisation he was able to get accuracy about 98.2%. I was trying to reproduce his results. But it seems it is not getting better with more layers.

Comment: Thank you for link. I will check it